# Options to sync 16GB+ KVM images

Tags: backup, kvm

Is there a software that sync KVM images in real time on ArchLinux?

i have 2 HDD that configured as RAID-0 (for performance reason) and 1 HDD for backup

i want to have a `real-time backup` images on raid0 to that backup partition

Comment: Do you run kvm directly or do you use some wrapper like libvirt?

Answer (score 1):

You say you use RAID0 for performance reasons, and this should indeed make your write and reads faster. But if you now add real-time backup to this device, this means that every write to it will also have to be written to the single backup disk, which will slow your write down to the speed of the slower backup HDD. If you do it right, you can still keep the increased read speed from the RAID0, but write will slow down remarkably.

Is that really what you want, or are you more looking for something like a backup that happens very often in the background? Then I'd recommend LVM with snapshots.

Otherwise, if you want to sacrifice your write speed for the real-time backup, you might want to play with a RAID1 md device on top of the RAID0 and the backup disk. By configuring it right you can keep your read speed if you just make sure that all the read goes to the RAID0 device.

Comment: it is also possible to do md raid1 with preferred read, have been using this with a nbd mirror.